# Get the new like growth with Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I am using the Facebook API to pull data in JSON format.

I need to pull the new likes growth from the pages that im not an admin.

```
$pageContent1 = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/' . $page . '/?fields=emails,about,website,category,likes.summary(true),location,new_like_count,name,were_here_count,cover,phone,posts&access_token=' . $token . '');
$parsedJson1 = json_decode($pageContent1);
```

Comment: As the documentation clearly states, `new_like_count` is only visible to page admins.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get this if you do one call on day one, and then another calls for every subsequent days if you're not an admin of the page.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/#reading

The only publically available insight metrics are `page_fans_country` and `page_storytellers_by_country`, but they are both lifetime metrics, meaning that you only get the absolute value.